# Is Hercule Poirot religious?

Tags: agatha-christie, hercule-poirot

I recently saw an episode of the Hercule Poirot series where he was portrayed as religious.

I have recently read the book the episode was based on and there is nothing about religion in the book.

In all the other Poirot books I have read (and I've read most of them) I don't remember any specific references to Poirot being religious (except the occasional Mon Dieu!).

So my question is if in her **books** Agatha Christie ever specifically indicates that Poirot is religious.

Comment: There is a very thorough answer to this question on Movies and TV SE here: https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/49241/was-hercule-poirot-always-religious

Comment: Was this question inspired by https://literature.stackexchange.com/q/722/139 "Is Sherlock Holmes religious"?

Comment: @b_jonas No, as I stated in the question I thought of it due to the series.

Comment: @Puzzlepumpkin You are right, that is a good answer. Can we import it to here as well?

Answer (score 1):

<sup>This answer is largely based on the [Movies & TV post](https://movies.stackexchange.com/a/49246/27759) which user1964 linked in a comment.</sup>

### Yes, Poirot was a religious Catholic.

In the story *Murder in Mesopotamia* ([Internet Archive link](https://archive.org/stream/agathachristie/Agatha%20Christie/English/Agatha%20Christie%20-%20Murder%20in%20Mesopotamia_djvu.txt)), he mentions twice that he is a "practising Catholic":

> Then he said quite irrelevantly: ‘An interesting man, that Father Lavigny.’
>
> ‘A monk being an archaeologist seems odd to me,’ I said.
>
> ‘Ah, yes, you are a Protestant. Me, I am a good Catholic. I know something of priests and monks.’
>
> [...]
>
> ‘I had a lengthy conversation with Father Lavigny. I am a practising Catholic and I know many priests and members of religious communities. Father Lavigny struck me as not ringing quite true to his role. But he struck me, on the other hand, as familiar in quite a different capacity. I had met men of his type quite frequently — but they were not members of a religious community. Far from it!’

In the later story *Taken at the Flood*, he even enters a Catholic church to pray:

> Moved by an impulse Poirot went through the gate and along the path to the door of the Roman Catholic building.
>
> He removed his hat, genuflected in front of the altar and knelt down behind one of the chairs. His prayers were interrupted by the sound of stifled heartbroken sobs.

His religion is not mentioned in earlier Poirot stories, but it's one of the things that helps to fill out, at least a little, the background of the character. Although he doesn't frequently refer to his religion, he also doesn't (as far as I know) say anything which *contradicts* him being religious: it's just not usually mentioned but occasionally comes up.